# <identifier> expected; can't update/set value in a class

Tags: java, identifier

For the following code I am getting error

> "identifier expected"

```
public class ConstructorChecking{     
    int a = 7;   
    int b=90;   
    String s="no";      
    a=a+1;   // for this line I am getting the error; why can't I update the value of a? 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
a=a+1;
```

is not valid in that scope

move that inside a method or a constructor...

and instead of doing **a = a + 1;** do **a++;**

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more why it's not valid in that scope. I understand we use method/constructor to update/set value. But I don't understand why I can't update/set those values of global variables without having them.

Comment: in the class scope you can either declare AND init in the same line or just declare.... late init must be done in a method/constructor

Comment: alright. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an init block

```
 int a = 7;   
    int b=90;   
    String s="no";      
    {
        a=a+1;   // for this line I am getting the error; why can't I update the value of a? 
    }
```